# create a simple DF after reading a parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a new developer on Scala and I met some problems to write a simple code on Spark Scala. I have this DF that I get after reading a parquet file :

```
ID   Timestamp
1    0
1    10
1    11    
2    20
3    15
```

And what I want is to create a DF result from the first DF (if the ID = 2 for example, the timestamp should be multiplied by two). So, I created a new class :

```
 case class OutputData(id: bigint, timestamp:bigint)
```

And here is my code :

```
val tmp = spark.read.parquet("/user/test.parquet").select("id", "timestamp")


  val outputData:OutputData = tmp.map(x:Row => {

  var time_result


  if (x.getString("id") == 2) {
     time_result = x.getInt(2)* 2 
  }

  if (x.getString("id") == 1) {
     time_result = x.getInt(2) + 10
  }


  OutputData2(x.id, time_result)

})

case class OutputData2(id: bigint, timestamp:bigint)
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please add more details, the title is: `create a simple DF from reading parquet`, but the description you are asking about how to process that data. So, your issue is reading the data? or how to apply your logic (assuming that you are able to read parquet file that is the title of your question)?

Comment: Done. I just edited the title !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the implementation easier, you can cast your `df` using a `case class`, the process that `Dataset` with object notation instead of access to your `row` each time that you want the value of some element. Apart of that, based on your input and output will take have same format you can use same case class instead of define 2.

Code looks like:

```
// Sample intput data
val df = Seq(
  (1,    0L),
  (1,    10L),
  (1,    11L),   
  (2,    20L),
  (3,    15L)
).toDF("ID", "Timestamp")
df.show()

// Case class as helper
case class OutputData(ID: Integer, Timestamp: Long)

val newDF = df.as[OutputData].map(record=>{
  val newTime = if(record.ID == 2) record.Timestamp*2 else record.Timestamp // identify your id and apply logic based on that
  OutputData(record.ID, newTime)// return same format with updated values
})

newDF.show()
```

The output of above code:

```
// original
+---+---------+
| ID|Timestamp|
+---+---------+
|  1|        0|
|  1|       10|
|  1|       11|
|  2|       20|
|  3|       15|
+---+---------+
// new one
+---+---------+
| ID|Timestamp|
+---+---------+
|  1|        0|
|  1|       10|
|  1|       11|
|  2|       40|
|  3|       15|
+---+---------+
```